# How to change an html class name using vba?

Tags: html, excel, vba

so I'm having a particular problem. Basically, what I'm trying to do is copy data from my excel and paste it into an internet explorer textbox. I've got as far as pasting it in and pressing the submit button on my webpage. However, my problem is that when using VBA, the submit button remains greyed out and cannot be pressed. The only times where it will not be greyed out is when I manually enter in the data into the textbox or manually paste it into the textbox without using VBA. the HTML code appears as such when the button is greyed out :

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
```

and when it is not greyed out :

```
<div class="form-group">
```

I was wondering if there's any way to change the class name to the second option through VBA, so that the button becomes clickable? I've tried dabbling with Set attribute, but im not sure if i'm doing it right because I keep getting error messages.

Any ideas?

Here's my full code for context:

```
Sub ExplorerTest3()
    'Requirement:
    ' In Tools / Reference : Enable Microsoft Internet controls
    ' In Tools / Reference : Enable Microsoft HTML Object library
    Const myPageURL As String = "https://intelcom.horasphere.com/app/#/report-module"
    Const mySearchForm As String = "searchform"
    Const mySearchInput As String = "searchInput"
    Const mySearchTerm As String = "Document Object Model"
    Const myButton As String = "Go"
    Dim myIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim ID As HTMLElementCollection
    Dim BtSearch As HTMLButtonElement
    Dim str As String
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim tableRow As Integer
    Dim tableCol As Integer

    ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    Sheets(5).Select
    'define sheetname here, if not sheet1
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5)
      ' the below brings back a number which can be used as lastcell. see below
      LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
      'here is the range
      My_Range_Is = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
      'iterate through range (start at 1 i.e.) end at last filled cell in column A (lastRow)
      For i = 1 To LastRow
          'do something here
      Next i
    End With

    Set myIE = CHECK_IE_ALREADY_OPEN("")
    arr = My_Range_Is
    For tableRow = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        For tableCol = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            str = str & arr(tableRow, tableCol) & vbTab
        Next tableCol
        str = str & vbNewLine
    Next tableRow

    With myIE
        .Navigate myPageURL
        Do While (.ReadyState <> 4) Or (.Busy = True)
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .Visible = True
        Set Doc = myIE.Document
        .Document.getElementsByClassName("report-module-query-category-item-button btn btn-default")(5).Click
        .Document.getElementsByClassName("report-link-button btn btn-default")(3).Click
        'Top 2 lines are to click on operation button and task states pivot button
        .Document.getElementsByClassName("report-module-query-execution-freeform-area")(0).Value = str
        Do While (.ReadyState <> 4) Or (.Busy = True)
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .Document.getElementsByClassName("pull-right report-module-query-list-execute-button btn btn-sm btn-default")(0).Click
    End With

End Sub
```

```
'.Document.getElementById(mySearchInput).Value = mySearchTerm
'.Document.getElementsByClassName("report-module-query-category-item-button btn btn-default")(5).Click

Function CHECK_IE_ALREADY_OPEN(ByVal URL As String) As Object
  Dim objShell As Object
  Dim objWindow As Object
  Dim objItem As Object
  Set CHECK_IE_ALREADY_OPEN = Nothing
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  On Error Resume Next ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
  Set objWindow = objShell.Windows()
  For Each objItem In objWindow
      If LCase(objItem.FullName) Like "*iexplore*" Then
          If objItem.LocationURL Like URL & "*" Then
              Set CHECK_IE_ALREADY_OPEN = objItem
              Exit For
          End If
      End If
  Next objItem
  On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: please post full code

Comment: Could you provide some of your code so we can see what you have done so far? It's possible a better solution might be firing an event vs you manually removing the class name.

Comment: I've put an edit with the full code in. Thanks!

Comment: Including the HTML for the textbox would probably be useful - likely it has some event handlers which are responsible for enabling the submit button - you may be able to trigger one of those after adding your content.

Comment: Just a note, I'd be careful hardcoding specific indexes when using `getElementsByClassName`. You could possibly look for more specific selectors or create a loop and look for something like the `innerText`.

Comment: Also, try to [avoid using select](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Style-Guide#avoid-using-select).